# importar csv a python

Tags: python, csv

Como puedo hacer un CSV con la lista de los grupos y poder importarlos al programa
gracias

```
NAME = 0
PUNTOS = 1
GROUP_NAMES = ['A', 'B',"C"]
GROUPA = [["Catar", 0], ["Ecuardor", 0], ["Senegal",0], ["Paises Bajos", 0]]   
GROUPB = [["Inglaterra", 0], ["Estados", 0], ["Iran",0], ["Gales", 0]]
GRUPOC = [["Argentina",0],["Polonia",0],["Mexico",0],["Arabia Saudita", 0]]
MUNDIAL = [GROUPA, GROUPB,GRUPOC]
```

Comment: Necesito hacer un csv con esas matrices e importarlo al programa

Comment: Falta que definas como quieres el .csv. Por favor, edita la pregunta y muestra como deseas el resultado.

Comment: Y también falta ver lo que has intentado, o pretendes que hagan las cosas por ti?

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener un archivo CSV a partir de cada una de las listas puedes utilizar de la librería `csv` de la siguiente manera

```py
import csv


def write_csv(filename, list_):
    """Escribe un archivo csv con los datos de la lista
    con el encabezado "Equipo", "Puntuación"
    :param filename: nombre del archivo
    :param list: lista de listas con los datos"""

    with open(filename, mode="w", encoding="utf-8") as out:
        csv_out = csv.writer(out)
        csv_out.writerow(["Equipo", "Puntuación"])
        for row in list_:
            csv_out.writerow(row)


group_A = [["Catar", 0], ["Ecuardor", 0], ["Senegal", 0], ["Paises Bajos", 0]]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    write_csv("group_A.csv", group_A)
```

Y esto da como resultado:

```
Equipo,Puntuación
Catar,0
Ecuardor,0
Senegal,0
Paises Bajos,0
```

En este ejemplo la función `write_csv` genera el archivo `group_A.csv` con el contenido de la lista `group_A` iterando sobre cada elemento de la lista para escribir cada renglón del archivo con la sentencia `csv_out.writerow`

Así que de esta forma utilizando la función `write_csv` puedes generar un archivo csv para cada una de tus listas

Comment: Sería más valioso tener toda la información en un sólo csv. ¿Puedes ampliar la respuesta?

Answer (score 0):

Solución alternativa:

Siendo tan simple el caso, no es necesario complicarse la vida con el módulo `csv`, basta con operaciones básicas de archivo.

```
with open('mundial.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    # Grabamos la primera línea del csv con los
    # nombres de los campos.
    csvfile.write("GROUP,NAME,PUNTOS\n")

    # Recorremos por grupo
    for id_grupo in GROUP_NAMES:
 
       # Formamos el nombre del grupo como texto
        # y luego lo usamos como llave en el diccionario
        # globals(), recuperando así el contenido
        # mismo del grupo
        grupo = globals()["GROUP" + id_grupo]

        # Ahora que tenemos los miembros del grupo,
        # los grabamos línea por línea 
        for equipo, puntos in grupo:
            csvfile.write(f"{id_grupo},{equipo},{puntos}\n")
```

#### Demo

```
NAME = 0
PUNTOS = 1
GROUP_NAMES = ['A', 'B',"C"]
GROUPA = [["Catar", 0], ["Ecuardor", 0], ["Senegal",0], ["Paises Bajos", 0]]
GROUPB = [["Inglaterra", 0], ["Estados", 0], ["Iran",0], ["Gales", 0]]
GROUPC = [["Argentina",0],["Polonia",0],["Mexico",0],["Arabia Saudita", 0]]
MUNDIAL = [GROUPA, GROUPB,GROUPC]

with open('mundial.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    # Grabamos la primera línea del csv con los
    # nombres de los campos.
    csvfile.write("GROUP,NAME,PUNTOS\n")

    # Recorremos por grupo
    for id_grupo in "ABC":

        # Formamos el nombre del grupo como texto
        # y luego lo usamos como llave en el diccionario
        # globals(), recuperando así el contenido
        # mismodel grupo
        grupo = globals()["GROUP" + id_grupo]

        # Ahora que tenemos los miembros del grupo,
        # los grabamos línea por línea
        for equipo, puntos in grupo:
            csvfile.write(f"{id_grupo},{equipo},{puntos}\n")
```

produce:

```
GROUP,NAME,PUNTOS
A,Catar,0
A,Ecuardor,0
A,Senegal,0
A,Paises Bajos,0
B,Inglaterra,0
B,Estados,0
B,Iran,0
B,Gales,0
C,Argentina,0
C,Polonia,0
C,Mexico,0
C,Arabia Saudita,0
```